Integrating PLC Pointer Data into TE2000 Environment in TwinCAT3
I'm working with TwinCAT3 and I have data stored in PLC pointers. I need to utilize this data in TE2000. Can anyone guide me on effectively utilizing PLC pointers data in the TE2000 environment?
here is what I have done:
Declaration:
PROGRAM MAIN
VAR
    stData              :ARRAY[0..9] OF ST_Data;
    pData               :POINTER TO ST_Data;
    nHMI_Request        :INT;
END_VAR

Loop
pData:=ADR(stData[nHMI_Request]);


What I was expecting was to be able to see the pointer data detail in the HMI.
